# Slack indicates unread messages in the tray icon even when set to only notify for mentions

Tags: notifications, slack, windows

I'm in a couple pseudo-public workspaces on Slack that have quite a bit of activity. I've gone into my settings for these workspaces and all the channels in them to make sure that I should only be notified if someone mentions me, yet my task tray icon insists on notifying me of *any* unread messages, even those that do not mention me. I don't get an audio indication, but I really don't even want to see the indicator in the tray icon. This results in the tray icon indicator being completely useless for the workspaces that I actually want to see indicators for since it effectively says I have unread messages at all times.

Is there a way to turn off tray icon notifications for specific workspaces?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about web apps but about the Windows Slack app and is too old to migrate to [su]

Answer (score 0):

As of September, 2023, on MacOS, there's a setting under "Notifications", called "Show a badge A dock badge on Mac on Slack's icon to indicate new activity". You can uncheck it to turn off the red dot on your app icon.

Here are instructions for various platforms:
https://zapier.com/blog/turn-off-red-dot-slack.